# What does assignment to a bracketed expression mean in C#?

Tags: c#, collection-initializer

I'm reading Avalonia source code and I came across this sentence:

```
return new MenuFlyoutPresenter
{
    [!ItemsControl.ItemsProperty] = this[!ItemsProperty],
    [!ItemsControl.ItemTemplateProperty] = this[!ItemTemplateProperty]
};
```

I've never seen a syntax like that. What does those bracket do if there is no indexed property or this[] accessor?, and why are they negated with the exclamation mark if the property they are referring to is not a bool?, maybe some kind of null-check?

The code itself is contained in the following cs file:

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Flyouts/MenuFlyout.cs

I've tracked the code but I was unable to understand what that syntax does.

Comment: It's a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

Comment: But collection initializers have curly braces don't they?, also, why are they negated?

Comment: No they don't, please read the section I linked to

Comment: @AleksanderStukov: Collection initializers come in two broad categories: for lists and for dictionaries.  This is the syntax used with dictionaries.  Also, the UED shouldn't have messed with Raynor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, the syntax:

```
var menu = new MenuFlyoutPresenter
{
    [key] = value,
};
```

Is a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), and is shorthand for:

```
var menu = new MenuFlyoutPresenter();
menu[key] = value;
```

That indexer is defined [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/4a172921588f1442c418df3b812dbff5699cbd6d/src/Avalonia.Base/AvaloniaObject.cs#L114) as:

```
public IBinding this[IndexerDescriptor binding]
{
    get { return new IndexerBinding(this, binding.Property!, binding.Mode); }
    set { this.Bind(binding.Property!, value); }
}
```

So the `key` there is an `IndexerDescriptor`, and the `value` is an `IBinding`.

So, what's going on with this thing?

```
!ItemsControl.ItemsProperty
```

We can see from your link that `ItemsProperty` is a `DirectProperty<TOwner, TValue>`, and that ultimately implements the `!` operator [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/4a172921588f1442c418df3b812dbff5699cbd6d/src/Avalonia.Base/AvaloniaProperty.cs#L159):

```
public static IndexerDescriptor operator !(AvaloniaProperty property)
{
    return new IndexerDescriptor
    {
        Priority = BindingPriority.LocalValue,
        Property = property,
    };
}
```

Avalonia seems to like overloading operators such as `!` and `~` to do things you might not expect (and would normally use a method for). In this case, they use `!` on an `AvaloniaProperty` as a shorthand for accessing that property's binding.

Comment: As far as I understand the collection initializer will be transformed into series of `.Add()` calls. The indexer is a property, so the the *first* must be a an *object initializer*, not collection initializer.

Comment: @Sinatr See my first link please. The syntax `new Foo() { { .., .. } }`, would be transformed into a series of `Add` calls, but the syntax `new Foo() { [..] = .. }` is transformed into a series of calls to the indexer. The documentation page I linked to documents this under "Collection initializers"

Comment: Although, it's true that the spec document this under object initializers. And the type doesn't need to implement `IEnumerable`, as it does for collection initializers. Eh

Answer (score 11):

A relatively simple class that demonstrates a way of allowing this syntax is:

```
public sealed class Demo
{
    public Demo this[Demo index] // Indexer
    {
        get => !index;
        set {} // Not needed to demonstrate syntax. 
    }

    public static Demo operator !(Demo item) => item;

    public Demo ItemsProperty        => _empty;
    public Demo ItemTemplateProperty => _empty;

    public Demo SomeMethod(Demo ItemsControl)
    {
        return new Demo
        {
            [!ItemsControl.ItemsProperty] = this[!ItemsProperty],
            [!ItemsControl.ItemTemplateProperty] = this[!ItemTemplateProperty],
        };
    }

    static Demo _empty = new();
}
```

Some things to note:

- `Demo` implements `operator!` which allows the `!` operator to be
  used on values of that type (e.g. the `!ItemsProperty` in the
  `SomeMethod()` initialisation).
- `Demo` implements an indexer which is what allows the use of the indexing (via `this`) on the right-hand side of the collection initialiser.
- The indexer also enables the use of the `[x] = y` collection initialisation syntax used in `SomeMethod()`.

It's the combination of the `operator()!` operator along with the `this[Demo]` indexer that enables the syntax.

Comment: that ! operator use is totall not instinctive. (I know not your idea). '!' to me means 'not' so `!Foo` means 'not foo'. Yet here it means foo. Why is it needed at all?

Comment: @pm100 The code in my answer is just an example to show how the syntax works - obviously in real code `operator!()` should be implemented to actually do something. However, I personally think the Avalonia code is abusing these operators and making the code very unintuitive and hard to read.